# How can I track the time pods are waiting to start?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to understand when pods are in a pending state because required resources aren't available to them to be scheduled..Is there a way to track time that pods are spending in "Pending" or "Scheduled" states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no other answers yet...so here we go:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

...will list events sorted by timestamp (replace `<namespace>` as appropriate).

For a concrete pod, this will output comma-delimited list of status changes and their timestamps:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get po/<pod-name> -o jsonpath="{range .status.conditions[*]}{.type}{','}{.lastTransitionTime}{'\n'}{end}"
```

From those, considering [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase), and a little scripting, it should be possible to derive the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`lastTransitionTime` under the `status.conditions` field in the pod manifest shows the timestamp of each intermediate state of the pod before it reaches `Running` state.

Timestamps below of the pod's transition `Initialized -> Ready -> ContainersReady -> PodScheduled`:

```
$ kubectl get pod coredns-fb8b8dccf-2lhl4 -n=kube-system -o json | jq '.status.conditions'
[
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2019-07-22T19:58:17Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Initialized"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2019-07-22T19:58:56Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Ready"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2019-07-22T19:58:56Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "ContainersReady"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2019-07-22T19:58:17Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "PodScheduled"
  }
]
```

After a pod is initialized, it is usually in `Pending` state until it is scheduled (`PodScheduled` state above) and reaches `Running` state.

Comment: So I have the python script that gets me the time elapsed in "Pending" state. However I am confused by the timestamps..For me the timestamp for "Initialized" state is bigger than the timestamp for "Pod Scheduled" ```('Initialized', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 24, 16, 26, 56, tzinfo=tzutc()))
('PodScheduled', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 24, 16, 26, 18, tzinfo=tzutc()))
-38``` The time elapsed in this case is 38 secs. Do the conditions in "Pending" go in the order as you mentioned, i.e Initialized -> Ready -> ContainersReady -> PodScheduled ?

Comment: I guess the order of transition you mentioned in your reply is not quite right..Upon reading the descriptions(https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions), I believe Scheduled should be the first thing..and then Initialized...then either ContainersReady or Ready...Still not sure what two timestamps should be used to compute time spent in "Pending"...

Comment: I agree with you. You should use `kubectl describe pods ` under events you can see Age and reasons for those pods, or directly in `kubectl get pods` you can notice State and Age.

Answer (score 0):

To display all pods - also in permanent "pending" state you can use:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.phase}{"\t"}{.status.startTime}{"\n"}{end}'



kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,POD:metadata.name,STATE:status.containerStatuses[*].state.waiting.reason,PHASE:status.phase
```

resources:

- [JSONPath Support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/),
- [kubectl Cheat Sheekubectl Cheat Sheett](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)